# Cant make images appear onclick in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I want to make images appear on click of a button. Say I input the word boy on the inputfields, in a press of the button, an image of a boy will appear. Been up all night long because of this. Here is the sample of my code

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GetAndSetText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField name;
    public InputField fname;
    public Text fText;
    public Image boy;

    public void sum()
    {
        boy = GetComponent<Image>();

        if (name.text == "hello") 
        {
            boy.sprite = (boy.jpg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `boy.sprite = (boy.jpg);` supposed to do? The [`Image`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html) component has no field or property `jpg`

Answer (score 1):

The [`Image`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html) component has no field or property `jpg` ...

But I guess what you are trying to archive is

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GetAndSetText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField name;
    public InputField fname;
    public Text fText;
    public Image boy;
    public Sprite sprite;

    public void sum()
    {
        boy = GetComponent<Image>();

        if (name.text == "hello") 
        {
            boy.sprite = sprite;
        }
    }
}
```

In the Unity Editor go to the Inspector of the imported Image file and set its `TextureType` to `Sprite(2D and UI)` and hit `Apply` (see the [Sprite Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Sprites.html)). Than reference it (Drag&Drop) in the `Sprite` field.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can create an `Image` and add the boy image to this. Then disable this game object.

[image: Image1]

Now, create a `Button` and `InputField` and a script like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SetImage : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject imageBoy;
    public InputField inputFieldName;

    public void ButtonOnClick()
    {
        if (inputFieldName.text == "boy")
            imageBoy.SetActive(true);
        else
            imageBoy.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Finally, click on the button, set the script to this and set `OnClick()` property:

[image: Image2]